# How do I install a .zip file via the command line?

Tags: command-line

How do I install a .zip file via the command line?

Comment: It would be helpful if you tell what is what you want to install.

Comment: You don't.  You install programs ( via the software center ).  A zip file is a compressed archive of arbitrary data files.

Comment: funny question :)

Answer (score 10):

You cannot install a zip file by itself. First unizip it (`unzip yourzipfilename.zip`) then navigate to the extracted folder (`cd yourzipfilename`), then install it's contents using command(s) that are appropriate to the content type.

Answer (score 3):

Just Double-click the .zip file -> Click `Extract`-> Select Destination Folder to extract. Its Done.

.zip is a compressed file not an installer.